# How do I join two tables in cognos with out any duplicate rows?

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, db2, cognos-10

I have a query written in ibm db2 sql which i would like to use in cognos frame work manager (FWM). The query uses multiple joins with other tables and it is joined on multiple hardcoded dates. I want to join the query in FWM and not consider the date logic but I am scared it may create multiple rows. How can I join it?

```
select ,emp_id,paid_amount ,outstanding_amt
from employees_tab e
join  reserve_table  c
on c.emp_id = e.emp_id
and  effective _date <'2018-01-01' and (end_date is null or end_date >= '2018-02-01'
```

Comment: your sql query is wrong, remove extra comma.

Answer (score 0):

try it:

```
select emp_id, paid_amount ,outstanding_amt
from employees_tab e
join  reserve_table  c
on c.emp_id = e.emp_id
where effective _date <'2018-01-01' and (end_date is null or end_date >= '2018-02-01');
```